# How to set the value of a data inside another component in Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have two vue components. One is opening the modal and the other is the content of that modal in the form of a table and a short form. After filling the form I want to click on the save button inside the component with the content, then save the content inside a array and close the modal. But the  component is in a different component and is binded to a field in the same component. I tried setting it to false by accessing the Component directly from my childcomponent but it does not work, eventhough I can console.log it and see it is false. Could someone look at my code?

DialogComponent:

html:

```
<v-dialog
          class="mx-auto my-auto "
          v-model="dialog"
          persistent
          max-width="fit-content"
          width="fit-content" >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-btn
              color="primary"
              dark
              v-bind="attrs"
              v-on="on"
              rounded
          >
            Add date
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">Generate Groups</span>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>

          </v-card-text>
          <v-divider class="mx-4"/>


          <AddGroupsModal :new-group.sync="meetingsArray"/>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
```

Script:

```
data : ()=>({
    dialog: false,
    menu: false,
    modal: false,
    menu2: false,
    menu3: false,
    meetingsArray: []

  }),
```

Child/Content:

```
generateGroup(){

     const newMeeting = {meetingUrl: "", meetingName: "", date: this.selectedDate, startTime: "", endTime: ""};
    let finalMeetingArray = [];

    this.model.forEach((model, i) => {
      const key = `participant${i + 1}`;
      newMeeting[key] = model.voterUniqueName;
      newMeeting.startTime = model.startTime;
      newMeeting.endTime = model.endTime
    })
    this.newGroup = [],
    finalMeetingArray.push(newMeeting)
    this.newGroup.push(newMeeting)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.newGroup))
    MeetingAdminComponent.data().dialog = false;  -> here I am trying to close the 
    modal
    console.log(MeetingAdminComponent.data().dialog) 

  }
```

Comment: You can notify changes with custom events: [$emit](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is possibly an Anti-pattern. Your code would be cleaner if you maintain separation and use the recommended parent/child communication from the official guide (see references below). They recommend using props to communicate with your child, or use emit events to communicate with your parent.

For example: your child would ...>

```
methods: {
 myMethod() {
  // Code ....
  // more code
  this.$emit('saved',somedata)
 }
}
```

You parent would listen ...>

```
<AddGroupsModal v-on:saved="doSomethingAfterSave"></AddGroupsModal>
```

References:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#listening-to-child-components-events

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried with `$refs`?

```html
<YourComponent ref="yourComponent" />
```

```js
methods: {
  dispatchChildMethod() {
    this.$refs.yourComponent.childMethod()
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks this worked out :) Another Question in this line: this.newGroup.push(newMeeting) I am pushing the content inside my prop and pass it like this:
<AddGroupsModal :new-group.sync="meetingsArray" ref="addGroupModal"/>

But the array meetingsarray is still empty. Do you know why?

Comment: It seems to be a reactivity issue. Virtual DOM is not reflecting in DOM after the push sentence. Try something tricky: put the push sentence into a `setTimeout()` method and check if it works. If I'm right, replacing `setTimeout` by `this.$nextTick(() => { // code here })` in your `generateGroup()` method should work too.

Comment: setTimeout(this.newGroup.push(newMeeting)) I changed the method like this but meetingArray is still empty. I know that newMeeting is not empty because if I console log it I am getting the values I want to have it

Comment: is `setTimeout(() => { this.newGroup.push(newMeeting) })`

Comment: Hey it worked now thanks :) Could you explain to me what this setTimeOut does exactly and why it worked this time?